# CakePHP ignores part of the argument passed to my IF statement

Tags: arrays, cakephp-2.0, if-statement

I have an array of 3 selected 'units' of different types (condos, hotels, houses).  In my view I am trying to display the different types of units differently according to their type.  Here is my code:

```
foreach($featured as $fc) {
        if($fc['Unit']['type'] = 'condo'): ?>
            ...display code here
        <?php  elseif($fc['Unit']['type'] = 'house'):  ?>
            ...display code here
        <?php  else:  
            ...display code here
     } ?>
```

It is ignoring whether it is a condo or house.  It displays all of my units as if they were condos.  Have I got my syntax wrong in my if statement?  I am used to using curly braces for everything but php.net showed elseif as using colons.  Sorry, I'm fairly new to php in general!

Comment: start by changing `=` to `==`

Comment: Derp derp derp, that did it!  Thanks!  Please post as the answer so I can give you credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With pleasure. You just need to change the `=` to `==`